# Stopping any loops when the windows 'X' (Close) button is clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7

I have a program which, when the begin button is clicked, it starts printing to the terminal in a loop. Which is fine. But when I close the window the loop continues printing to the terminal. which I don't want. So I am wondering if theirs a way to access the windows 'X' (preferably using PyQt5) to run a function which closes the entire program.

I don't know if you need all the code, so... I just added the loop function I am using.

I've tried to search for a solution. However, the solutions I have found have all been for PyQt4 and haven't worked for me.

```py
# I have tried using this to close the program
app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.close) # didn't work... Did nothing.

#close function    
    def close(self):
        exit()
# I am using this an infinite loop (for testing purposes.)
    def start(self, activate):
        self.activate = activate
        print(self.activate)

        self.Stop_BTN.setEnabled(True)
        self.Start_BTN.setEnabled(False)

        if (self.activate != 1):
            pass
            return
        else:
            while (self.activate == 1):
                print('IDK just needed something to put here.')
                QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say *when the button is clicked, it starts printing to the terminal in a loop. Which is fine* it seems that you do not know how Qt works. It is not good that in the main thread tasks are executed continuously since they block the eventloop of the GUI and consequently the window freezes. The most approximate is that this impression is every certain interval of time, and that time interval is small(for example 1 ms), with a QTimer.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1000)

        self.m_start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start printing")
        self.m_close_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close window")
        self.m_close_button.setDisabled(True)

        self.m_timer.timeout.connect(self.printing_task)
        self.m_start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)
        self.m_close_button.clicked.connect(self.close)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_start_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_close_button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start_timer(self):
        self.m_start_button.setDisabled(True)
        self.m_close_button.setDisabled(False)
        self.m_timer.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def printing_task(self):
        print("IDK just needed something to put here.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```